# Pass the custom list value adapter to activity

Tags: android, android-bundle

I am using Retrofit concept, I need to pass the list value to activity. Here I attached the code where I get the response from backend.

```
private void callCheckTopCourseDetails(String getId) {
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<Example> call2 = apiInterface.doGetWishlist(getId);
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            if (response.code() == RESPONSECODE_200 || response.code() == RESPONSECODE_201) {
                List<RatingsDetail> getRatingDetails = response.body().getAndroid().getRatingsDetails();
                List<CourseDetail> getCourseDetail = response.body().getAndroid().getCoursedetails();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("ttttttttt", "" + t);
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a clear outline of the exact issue and a summary of what you tried.

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("RatingDetails", String.valueOf(getRatingDetails));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CourseDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent); i am tried like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed like this,its working for me

```
  private void callCheckTopCourseDetails(String getId) {
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<Example> call2 = apiInterface.doGetWishlist(getId);
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            if (response.code() == RESPONSECODE_200 || response.code() == RESPONSECODE_201) {

                List<RatingsDetail> getRatingDetails = response.body().getAndroid().getRatingsDetails();
                List<CourseDetail> getCourseDetail = response.body().getAndroid().getCoursedetails();
                String getratingcouts = response.body().getAndroid().getRatingsCounts().getMembercount();
                String gettotcount=response.body().getAndroid().getRatingsCounts().getTotalrating();
                int getcalc=response.body().getAndroid().getRatingsCounts().getCalculation();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("RatingDetails", (Serializable) getRatingDetails);
                bundle.putSerializable("CourseDetails", (Serializable) getCourseDetail);
                bundle.putString("getembercount",getratingcouts);
                bundle.putString("gettotcount",gettotcount);
                bundle.putInt("gettotcount",getcalc);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CourseDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("ttttttttt", "" + t);
            call.cancel();
        }

    });

}
```